# Android Calendar Month/Week view like this

Tags: android, calendar, material-design

I'm making an android app, it needs to be exactly the same as the example below. Now I'm stuck at the calendar/date picker, I need a couple of tips and tricks to turn this in a library, or there is already one?

[image]

Comment: Got any solution?

Comment: @shubh I could send you the source of what I have now, but wasn’t able to succeed.

Comment: I found this library - https://github.com/shrikanth7698/Collapsible-Calendar-View-Android